# Unable to consume GraphQl api and getting "POST body missing, invalid Content-Type, or JSON object has no keys." error

Tags: javascript, next.js, apollo, knex.js, apollo-server

Unable to consume GraphQl API and getting "POST body missing, invalid Content-Type, or JSON object has no keys." error.

I have created GraphQl api using Next.js 13, Knex.js and apollo but when I am accessing the endpoint from apollo GraphQl explorer or other tools like postman I am getting this error:

> POST body missing, invalid Content-Type, or JSON object has no keys.

I have also tried to use hardcoded data instead of fetching from the database, but nothing is working.

My Schema.ts file:

```
import { gql } from "apollo-server-micro";

// Define the GraphQL schema for Transaction
const typeDefs = gql`
  type Transaction {
    id: ID!
    userId: ID!
    paymentRequest: String!
    paymentHash: String!
    paymentSecret: String!
    amount: Float!
    accountType: String!
    Wallet: String!
    status: String!
    createdAt: String!
    updatedAt: String!
  }

  type Query {
    getAllTransactions: [Transaction]!
  }
export default typeDefs;
```

my resolver.ts file

```
import { json } from "stream/consumers";
import knexConfig from "../../config/knexfile";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

const knexConfigObj = knexConfig["development"];
const knex = require("knex")(knexConfigObj);

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    getAllTransactions: async () => {
      return await knex("transactions").select("*");
    },
  },
};

export default resolvers;
```

my index.ts file in api/graphql folder

```
import { ApolloServer } from "apollo-server-micro";
import resolvers from "../../../graphql/transactions/resolvers";
import typeDefs from "../../../graphql/transactions/schema";
import Cors from "micro-cors";

const cors = Cors();
const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers });
const startServer = apolloServer.start();

// Start the server
export default cors(async function (req: any, res: any) {

  await startServer;
  await apolloServer.createHandler({
    path: "/api/graphql",
  })(req, res);
});

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};
```

schema for table

```
export async function up(knex: Knex): Promise<void> {
  return knex.schema.createTable("transactions", function (table) {
    table.uuid("id").primary();
    table.uuid("user_id").notNullable();
    table.string("payment_request").notNullable();
    table.string("payment_hash").notNullable();
    table.string("payment_secret").notNullable();
    table.decimal("amount").notNullable();
    table.string("account_type").notNullable();
    table.string("wallet").notNullable();
    table
      .enu("status", ["funded", "unfunded", "paid"])
      .notNullable()
      .defaultTo("unfunded");
    table.timestamp("created_at").defaultTo(knex.fn.now());
    table.timestamp("updated_at").defaultTo(knex.fn.now());
  });
}

export async function down(knex: Knex): Promise<void> {
  return knex.schema.dropTable("transactions");
}
```

and KnexFile.ts

```
import type { Knex } from "knex";

// Update with your config settings.

const config: { [key: string]: Knex.Config } = {
  development: {
    client: "postgresql",
    connection: {
      host: "localhost",
      user: "postgres",
      password: "password",
      database: "postgres",
    },
    migrations: {
      tableName: "knex_migrations",
    },
  },
.
.
.
//other enviroment 

export default config
```

this is query I am trying.

```
query ExampleQuery {
  getAllTransactions{
    userId
  }
}
```

dependencies

```
    "@apollo/client": "^3.7.14",
    "@graphql-tools/load-files": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/node": "20.1.5",
    "@types/react": "18.2.6",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.4",
    "apollo-server-micro": "^3.12.0",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.14",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "eslint": "8.40.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.2",
    "graphql": "^16.6.0",
    "knex": "^2.4.2",
    "micro": "^10.0.1",
    "micro-cors": "^0.1.1",
    "next": "^13.4.3",
    "pg": "^8.11.0",
    "postcss": "8.4.23",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-qrcode-logo": "^2.9.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.2",
    "typescript": "5.0.4",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0"
```

these are all files I think will be used during this process